# Campo Calculado JPA Spring Boot

Tags: jpa, spring-boot

Gostaria de auxílio para buscar um campo calculado.
O problema é que o mesmo envolve relacionamentos.

Preciso calcular o total de uma Venda com vários Itens de Venda (produtos).
O total parcial por Item de Venda (preço do produto * quantidade) é calculado corretamente.

Porém quando vou valvular o total da Venda o total do Item de Venda vem null, nestes códigos:

```
// Item de Venda
@Transient
private Double total;

// Este código funciona ao consultar os itens de venda (separadamente)
public Double getTotal() {
    return this.product.getPrice() * this.quantity;
}
```

---

```
// Venda
@Transient
private Double total;

public Double getTotal() {
    if (!sellItems.isEmpty()) {
        for (SellItem item : sellItems){
            // Essa linha dá NullPointer pois o valor é null.
            this.total += item.getTotal();
        }
    }

    return this.total;
}
```

Comment: Olhe a minha resposta aqui, por favor =)

Answer (score 1):

O valor padrão de uma variável Double em Java é null, portanto quando você declara uma variável sem inicializá-la o seu valor inicial será null. Inicialize a variável total com o valor zero primeiro como a seguir:

```
public Double getTotal() {
    this.total= new Double(0.0);

    if (!sellItems.isEmpty()) {
        for (SellItem item : sellItems){
            // Essa linha dá NullPointer pois o valor é null.
            this.total += item.getTotal();
        }
    }

    return this.total;
}
```